# Make text selected in tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to add a search feature in my website. in which i want to search contents in tinymce editor and make them selected if match found.

how can i make text selected if match .If any one know please reply
[image]

Comment: If the search is in a single page, then the browser's built-in _find in page_ functionality is the simplest solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not so difficult. Easiest thing is to have a look at the searchNext-function of the searchreplace plugin (i will add the code bellow).

The plugin code gets executed in a tinymce popup context, so you will need to tweak it a bit. Here are the varibales you will need to set in advance to make the function work:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
var se = ed.selection;
var r = se.getRng();
// var m = this.lastMode; // not needed here
var fl = 0;
var w = ed.getWin();
var wm = ed.windowManager;
var fo = 0;
//var f = document.forms[0];  //not needed here (plugin relevant)
var s = 'word_to_be_searched_for';
var b = 0; // direction of the search (forward=0, backward = 1)
var ca = 0; // casesensitiviy of the search (not casesensitive = 0, casesensitive = 1)
var rs = ''; // possibility to use a string to replace found text
```

Here is the function:

```
searchNext : function(a) {
    var ed = tinyMCEPopup.editor, se = ed.selection, r = se.getRng(), f, m = this.lastMode, s, b, fl = 0, w = ed.getWin(), wm = ed.windowManager, fo = 0, err = 0;

    // Get input
    f = document.forms[0];
    s = f[m + '_panel_searchstring'].value;
    b = f[m + '_panel_backwardsu'].checked;
    ca = f[m + '_panel_casesensitivebox'].checked;
    rs = f['replace_panel_replacestring'].value;

    if (tinymce.isIE) {
        r = ed.getDoc().selection.createRange();
    }

    if (s == '')
        return;

    function fix() {
        // Correct Firefox graphics glitches
        // TODO: Verify if this is actually needed any more, maybe it was for very old FF versions? 
        r = se.getRng().cloneRange();
        ed.getDoc().execCommand('SelectAll', false, null);
        se.setRng(r);
    };

    function replace() {
        ed.selection.setContent(rs); // Needs to be duplicated due to selection bug in IE
    };

    // IE flags
    if (ca)
        fl = fl | 4;

    switch (a) {
        case 'all':
            // Move caret to beginning of text
            ed.execCommand('SelectAll');
            ed.selection.collapse(true);

            if (tinymce.isIE) {
                ed.focus();
                r = ed.getDoc().selection.createRange();

                while (r.findText(s, b ? 1 : 1, fl)) {
                    r.scrollIntoView();
                    r.select();
                    replace();
                    fo = 1;

                    if (b) {
                        r.moveEnd("character", -(rs.length)); // Otherwise will loop forever
                    }
                }

                tinyMCEPopup.storeSelection();
            } else {
                while (w.find(s, ca, b ? 0 : 0, false, false, false, false)) {
                    replace();
                    fo = 1;
                }
            }

            if (fo)
                tinyMCEPopup.alert(ed.getLang('searchreplace_dlg.allreplaced'));
            else
                tinyMCEPopup.alert(ed.getLang('searchreplace_dlg.notfound'));

            return;

        case 'current':
            if (!ed.selection.isCollapsed())
                replace();

            break;
    }

    se.collapse(b);
    r = se.getRng();

    // Whats the point
    if (!s)
        return;

    if (tinymce.isIE) {
        ed.focus();
        r = ed.getDoc().selection.createRange();

        if (r.findText(s, b ? -1 : 1, fl)) {
            r.scrollIntoView();
            r.select();
        } else
        {
            err = 1;
            tinyMCEPopup.alert(ed.getLang('searchreplace_dlg.notfound'));
        }
        tinyMCEPopup.storeSelection();
    } else {
        if (!w.find(s, ca, b, false, false, false, false))
        {
            err = 1;
            tinyMCEPopup.alert(ed.getLang('searchreplace_dlg.notfound'));
        }
        else
            fix();
    }

    // Focus input field if search yieled no error
    if (!err && !tinymce.isIE) {
        f[m + '_panel_searchstring'].focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: i use the above code and changed the editor id in ed variable and set the search word in s variable but i cant make them selected below is the code  ``function searchnotes(){


var snote=$('#txt_name').val();

var ed = tinymce.get("txtnotes");
var se = ed.selection;

var r = se.getRng();
//setRng(r);

var fl = 0;
var w = ed.getWin();

var wm = ed.windowManager;
var fo = 0;

var s = snote;
alert(r);
var b = 0; 
var ca = 0; 
var rs = ''; 
}

Comment: i voted this down as it is unreadable, can you use proper variable names? It's hard to see what is going on here